# Required prop in Vue 3 is not throwing any errors if missing on component call

Tags: vuejs3

I'm actually developing a new app with Vue 3 (3.2.31) and the composition API.
I already used Vue 2 with the options API a long time and never had any problem with prop validation.

However I need to make a components prop required in  which should work with the following code:

ComponentA

```
<script setup>
const props = defineProps({
    pageName: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
});

...
</script>
```

Calling ComponentA in ComponentX

```
<component-a>
```

This should throw any errors because page-name is required in Component A?
Am I missing something?

There should be any error because of the missing required prop which is not passed to the component

Comment: If you're expecting an IDE error you'll need to use typescript, otherwise the expected behavior is just a warning in your browser's dev console.  See the [docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html#prop-validation) "If a requirement is not met, Vue will warn you in the browser's JavaScript console"